# Oracle Select with Date and Format

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm really new to anything to do with Oracle and I have been given this query;

```
...BETWEEN TO_DATE('" + shortStartDate + "','MMDDYYYY') 
  AND TO_DATE('" + shortEndDate + "','MMDDYYYY')"
```

shortStartDate and shortEndDate are dates entered in the format of whatever part of the world you occupy.

However, looking at the string, it seems to indicate to me that it's expecting `MMDDYYYY` format is that right?  Or is it converting the date to `MMDDYYYY`?

How can I re-write this to be region independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbed [from here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

The syntax for the TO_DATE function is:

TO_DATE( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )
string1 is the string that will be converted to a date.

format_mask is optional. **This is the format that will be used to convert string1 to a date**.

Examples:

```
TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')
```

would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002

```
TO_DATE('" + shortStartDate + "','MMDDYYYY')
```

would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002 if shortStartDate =' 03152002'

To format your date in C# you would simply use the `ToString` like

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("mmddyyyy");
```

Comment: So does that mean that if my string1 was in dd/mm/yyyy format, that the resultant query will be converted to mmddyyyy format?

Comment: no the date object you pass in to TO_DATE function uses the format MMDDYYYY to convert the string to a date object. So it will expect the string to represent the date in exactly this format.
If you read the linked article, it gives you some examples...
TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd') would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002

Comment: Oh OK, I get it.  So now how would I internationalize this so it can be used in the States as well as Europe and Australia?

Comment: please mark this as answered and ask a new question as comments are not the best place to keep track ;)
And tbh, I have no clue, you would have to format your variables in a way that you don't have to change the sql string everytime I guess?
Using string.Format?

Comment: My question did include a section for region independence.  :)  OK great.  I'll play around a bit with the region stuff.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @griegs ups, ok ;) yeah as I said, I guess you would want to format your date object to a string which is always compatible with the statement right? So I don't know if the above code comes from a C# project, but if so, `DateTime` internally doesn't know about any culture, it just stores the ticks. So you can format it in any way you want, e.g. DateTime.Now.ToString("mmddyyyy"); which would give you exactly the string you need.